# Choppy video with HD--is there an easy way to downsample or lower the quality so that my videos will play correctly?

Tags: video

I have a somewhat older computer, and it's fine with most things, but on super high-res video it's choppy and the CPU's at 100%. Should I downsample these videos, or is there a setting that I can use to make them play without stopping?

Comment: difficult to say - what graphics card and what graphics driver are you using?  What version of ubuntu? what type of video? What resolution?

Answer (score 2):

You have to downsample them before playing them. (Might take a few hours and you loose quality.)

The hard work is really decoding the video and not displaying it. That means no matter if you display a lower resolution video, the work is all the same.